# Variable declared but never used

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[new to Vue here]
I have seen a lot of similar questions, but no answers that would help me solve my error.

I am building a small Vue project and I am now trying to separate it into smaller components and views.

My router.js looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Jobs from './components/Jobs.vue'
import Companies from './components/Companies.vue'
import Events from './components/Events.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router ({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/jobs',
      name: 'jobs',
      component: 'Jobs'
    },
    {
      path: '/companies',
      name: 'companies',
      component: 'Companies'
    },
    {
      path: '/events',
      name: 'events',
      component: 'Events'
    }
  ]
})
```

And for the rest you can check out this repo, has very few files https://github.com/anaivanm/vue-tw/
This error is driving me nuts and I have no idea why it's not compiling.

```
./src/router.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'Jobs' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/router.js:3:8:
  1 | import Vue from 'vue'
  2 | import Router from 'vue-router'
> 3 | import Jobs from './components/Jobs.vue'
    |        ^
  4 | import Companies from './components/Companies.vue'
  5 | import Events from './components/Events.vue'
  6 |
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's [eslint](https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/user-guide/#installation) complaining, apparently when you have created the project using Vue CLI you set linter to use some linting rules, such as 'air bnb'

Comment: But the Jobs component is used in the Router, so the linter shouldn't complain, unless it's configured wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use single-quotes in `component: 'Jobs'` what you probably wanted to do is to use your component instead:

```
...
import Jobs from './components/Jobs.vue'
...

export default new Router ({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/jobs',
      name: 'jobs',
      component: Jobs
    },
...
```

Make sure that you've configured Vue.Router exactly as explained on its [official page](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript).

Here is a quote from there:

```
// 2. Define some routes
// Each route should map to a component. The "component" can
// either be an actual component constructor created via
// `Vue.extend()`, or just a component options object.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```